# Infinities of Counting Measure

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the counting measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}), \mu)$; the definition of counting measure is
$$\mu(A) = 
\begin{cases}
|A| &\text{if }A\text{ is finite} \\
+\infty &\text{if }A\text{ is infinite}
\end{cases}$$
where $|A|$ is the cardinality of $A$.

Under this definition, $\mu(\mathbb{N}) = +\infty$ and $\mu([0,1]) = +\infty$. Does this mean that $\mu(\mathbb{N}) = \mu([0,1])$ even though $\mathbb{N}$ is a countable set but $[0,1]$ is an uncountable set? Also, is the $+\infty$ in the definition of measure countable or uncountable?

Comment: $\infty$ is neither countable nor uncountable. It has no such meaning. $\infty$ is simply the largest element in the ordered set of the extended reals. But yes, the measure of both $\mathbb N$ and $[0,1]$ are $\infty$, since this measure doesn't do well with comparing infinite sets.

Comment: Agree with @DonThousand, the issue is with the counting measure you are using, it clumps together all the different kinds of infinity, and $+\infty$ is being merely used as a big placeholder symbol.